# Show configurable product descriptions only, not simple products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product

In Magento2. How do you set all configurable products in the front-end to only show the description and short description of the main configurable product. Not the descriptions of the simple products?

It seems by default, that when you toggle and change between colours and sizes, it pulls the description content from the simple product that has been selected. Not the main configurable product.

We have a store with circa 10,000 products, where the simple products have description fields empty. So want to pull from the main configurable product where the descriptions are completed for main description and short description.

Comment: are you able to make your question clearer? maybe give example as I am at lost to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Done. Updated the question now. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, will look into this

Comment: ok, I have a basic Magento instance with luma theme sample data.. and whilst changing the parent description does change my main description on the frontend indeed... at no point, selecting size/colour does change my description.. hinting me you have a module doing the swap for you..

Comment: Have you eventually resolve your issue? please feel free to post it again as some other people may have more ideas

Comment: No, still not resolved.

Comment: Thanks. This looks good. If the simple product is not empty for the description, will it still take the configurable version? In our situation, I think we need some sort of statement that always takes the configurable description. If there is a simple product on it's own, then it uses it's description.

Comment: Might be time for bounty

Comment: Added bounty now.

Comment: Sounds good, no doubt you’ll have your issue sorted. Now, you still want to bear in mind we have not found the root of your problem

Comment: Well, it isn't so much a problem, in that we just need a workaround created in child theme probably, for the product page, that says "if configurable has simple product, then use configurable description". The simple is being shown, because the description field is added on all simple products.

Comment: ok, module is updated and product description is now coming from parent product whether it is empty or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108916/discussion-between-herve-tribouilloy-and-magentomac).

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, looks to me like you have a module doing some logic for you in your Magento store.

--> the solution may be to find what is the customisation that does this and alter it with a config for instance?

Having said that, if you really need a fix, I can either recommend a command that would assign the descriptions of your main products to all its simple

Or you may prefer a plugin that takes over getDescription method of the product model; if the product is a simple without description, it would pull its description from the parent: using the registry to pull the description, this does not give any overhead on your store.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will look into integrations overriding Magento2 default then. Not looking for updating the product data, as when new products are fed in from the EPOS system, the problem will re-occur. So looking to change the code making this change. We have some plugins from Amasty enabled, but can't see any affecting the product page content. Will disable 1 by 1 and try to work out what is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Still working on a solution for this. Are you sure this is default Magento2 to have only the configurable descriptions show? Our testing suggest it's the opposite, in that it will pull the simple description as the description to show on selection of the colour or size for that simple product while on the configurable in frontend. Surprised nobody else has hit this issue. Can't find any other posts about?

Comment: I admit it could make sense but I also can't see this as a default feature by intuition. As previously mentioned, on my local (default magento 2.3.3 with sample data, I do not have this behaviour). Now, the fix is simple and I can provide you with the code for it

Comment: Do the simple products in your sample data have blank short descriptions? Or data in each?

Comment: since I use the sample data, the simple had same description as the parent and I did overwrite the simple and then selected the relevant options.. and yet the parent description was displayed

Comment: Is there possibly a visibility component to the issue?

Comment: @iphigenie not for us sorry. The simple products are set not to be visual individually. So only pulled as part of configurable.

Comment: @magentoMac you say you have modules but none obviously about product content - look at any that are navigation or seo, as it is often a feature to have a structured landing URL for each option combination and that might have added content swap

Comment: You mentioned Amasty - Are you using Colour Swatches for example, to get the pretty matrixes? Look at the Reloadable Information Settings options

Comment: @iphigenie this was it!!!! Thanks for the suggestion. Totally overlooked that setting and didn't really understand what it did. Disabling short description from that setting has resolved.

Comment: excellent! Glad the time I wasted reading in descriptions and manuals of extensions trying to find a solution to my issues can be of use to someone :)